# Using JSON to create a leveling system for my discord server

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hi im creating a bot for a discord server that levels up users when they chat and just for the sake of being able to check everything works, there are lines that are temporary that message where its at in processing the data. Heres the code:

```
async def add_xp(amount, user, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return

        elementlist = []

        with open("users/" + user + ".json", "r") as testfile:
            data = json.load(testfile)
            await message.channel.send("file loaded 1")

        for element in data:
            await elementlist.append(data[element])
            await message.channel.send(element + ":", data[element])

        level = elementlist[0]
        xp = elementlist[1]
        xp_to_next = elementlist[2]
        await message.channel.send("variables initialised")

        xp += amount
        await message.channel.send("XP updated")

        if xp >= xp_to_next:
            xp -= xp_to_next
            level += 1
            xp_to_next = xp_to_next * 2
            await message.channel.send("Level Up")

        data = {"level": level,
                "xp": xp,
                "xp_to_next": xp_to_next}
        await message.channel.send("data declared")

        with open("users/" + user + ".json", "w") as testfile:
            await json.dump(data, testfile)
            await message.channel.send("Data Dumped")


async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!')

    with open("users/" + str(member) + ".json", "a") as testfile:
        data = {"level": 0,
                "xp": 0,
                "xp_to_next": 0}
        data = json.dump(data, testfile)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    user = str(message.author)
    add_xp(1, user, message)
```

and get an output of:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/DAN/1/8/0/1/PROGRAMMING/LegacyCoding/DiscordTutorialBot/Bot1/Test1.py", line 77, in on_message
    await add_xp(1, user, message)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/DAN/1/8/0/1/PROGRAMMING/LegacyCoding/DiscordTutorialBot/Bot1/Test1.py", line 23, in add_xp
    with open("users/" + user + ".json", "r") as testfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users/danhowe0#2790.json'
```

In the `on_member_join()` function, it should send a message to the user saying welcome and also initialise the file for the variables to be stored in. However it does neither of these and i cant seem to fix it. If anyone could help it would be extremely useful!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but are you perhaps missing the `@client.event` decorator for `on_member_join`?

Comment: @hmm well then.... that fixed it hahaha

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue as me check that all your decorators (`@client.event`) are in front of the functions. I missed one out and that was what was causing my problems!